# SQL conditional insert on SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

Hi I have 2 tables below:

table1

```
GroupName PersonName email phone
A         Tom        tom@  123
A         Jen        jen@  223
B         Kim        kim@  232
```

table2

```
GroupName PersonName email phone
A         Tom        NULL  1
A         Jen        NULL  1
A         Ken        NULL  1
B         Kim        NULL  1
B         Tai        NULL  1
```

I need to insert all columns of the additional records from `table2` into `table1`. for example, I need `Ken` and `Tai's` records from `table2` added to `table1`. it's running on **SQL Server 2000** so I cannot use `EXCEPT` or `INTERSECT`.

Comment: what do you want to insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming email is unique:

```
insert into table1
select * from table2
where email not in (select email from table1)
```

alternative:

```
insert  into table1
select  a.* 
from    table2 a
        LEFT JOIN table1 b
            ON a.email = b.email
WHERE   b.email IS NULL
```

Comment: use `JOIN` instead of `IN` :)

Comment: `JOIN`s are way aster than `IN`

Comment: sorry - email is actually NULL in table2 - pls see my edit. thanks

Comment: If you want to get technical, use `OUTER JOIN` instead of IN. But performance is not an absolute. based on the sample data, IN is more than adequate. You could also use `NOT EXISTS` which might be faster for a larger dataset

Answer (score 0):

this will do it..

```
Inser Table1
select  GroupName, PersonName, email, phone
from Table2 where  GroupName+'|'+PersonName+'|'+email+'|'+phone 
    not in (select GroupName+'|'+PersonName+'|'+email+'|'+phone from Table1)
```

Thanks!

@leo.